# table with colspan attribute not resizing

Tags: jquery, resize, html-table

I am trying to make a table re-sizable using colResizable-1.3.min.js. while re-sizing the dotted line is shown verifying the column is being re-sized but when I stopped dragging and released the mouse the column width is not changing. In the debugger the changed width is visible but the width of the element is not changing.

Comment: Sample code or fiddle please.

Comment: Its a bug in the library:  http://zydecodigital.com/test-col-resize.html

Answer (score 0):

You must of placed a style on the table that is forcing the columns to be a specific size or you're using an obsolete version of jQuery.

Changing the size of a colspan column works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/qEMrZ/  in FF 22.

```
$("#btnBigger").click(function() {
    var w = $("#col2").width();
    alert(w);
    w = w * 2;
    $("#col2").width(w);
    alert(w);
});
$("#btnSmaller").click(function() {
    var w = $("#col2").width();
    alert(w);
    w = Math.floor(w / 2);
    $("#col2").width(w);
    alert(w);
});
```

Comment: He's using the colresizable library not just jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug.  This post is old and I'm using v1.5 of the library.  To fix change line 87 of colResizable-1.5.source.js to

`var th = t.find(">thead>tr:first>th,>thead>tr:first>td");`

As per col resiable instructions make sure your first thead row has no colspan columns.  I set the style of this row to visibility:hidden in my code.